# Solve $I[y]=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1+(y')^2)^\frac{1}{2} \mathrm dx$ parametrically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

If $$I[y]=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}F(x,y,y') \mathrm dx$$
Where $$F=y^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1+(y')^2)^\frac{1}{2}$$
Then I have shown the Euler-Lagrange equation implies that
$$y(1+(y')^2)=2a$$
For some $a\geq0$. If originally $x=y=0$ can anyone help me show that the parametric solution to this problem is the following?
$$x=a(t-\operatorname{sin}t)$$
$$y=a(1-\operatorname{cos}t)$$

Comment: If you have the solution, you can just plug it in and check that it is true. Note that $y'= \frac{\dot y}{\dot x}$

Comment: Thank you, I was being an idiot there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=a(t-\operatorname{sin}t)$$
$$y=a(1-\operatorname{cos}t)$$
Implies
$$\dot{x}=a(1-\operatorname{cos}t)$$
$$\dot{y}=a\operatorname{sin}t$$
Then $$y'=\frac{\operatorname{sin}t}{1-\operatorname{cos}t}$$
Therefore
$$y(1+(y')^2)=\frac{a(1-2\operatorname{cos}t+1)}{1-\operatorname{cos}t}=2a$$
Therefore it parametrically describes the solution.